# Can someone translate this chinese letter?

Tags: translation

I received this letter from my crush. Please help me translate this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very touching and the handwriting is quite decent, but why did you ate your aunt? Tell him to rely less on machine translation. Also according to the rules, posts asking for translations will get closed.

Comment: Hand writing is decent? Dude the handwriting is terrible. It's probably written by a kid, for a kid it's probably decent but not for adults. I tried reading part of it and it doesn't make much sense, it's like google translate wrote this letter

Comment: Perhaps you can type this out, feed it into Google Translate, and voila! The original English letter will appear.

Comment: @Huangism I only wish the handwriting I see in China was this "terrible"!  This is very clear.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty yes clear but clear != decent

Comment: @Huangism decent for a non-native speaker who seems have quite limited knowledge of Chinese. Do you get a lot of fun tougue-lashing newbies?

Comment: @WangDingwei don't assume the writer is a non-native, it's kids writing.

Comment: bro the person who wrote this doesn't know 10  words of Chinese and is an Indian.She wrote the best she could after translating each word from english.

Answer (score 5):

First I have try my best reenter all the words, although the grammar was very bad.
I try my best to translate to you.

Note: I only translate what I know.

**PS**: Sorry for the bad English

```
只是我亲爱的(your name here)到，
```

Dear lovely (your name here) only,

```
这是我们的一年的今天。我是们整个作出这一年在一起我们的漂亮非常第一次。你极其最了不起的人，我知道。
```

Today is our first anniversary. We did it very beautiful for the first time. You are the most wonderful man, I know.

```
你可以总是把一个巨大的微笑在我的脸上没有每第二次尝试即使我跟你只是花似乎使我更快乐和甚至爱你这么多的更多。
```

You always put a big smile on my face with first try although you and me was just (flower)?? seems to make me happier and even love you so much.

```
这是我们一年的今天。我们取得了一整个美丽年在一起我们第一次。你非常的最了不起的人，我知道。
```

Today is our first anniversary. We obtain a beautiful year for our first time together. You are a very wonderful man, I know.

```
没有甚至尝试只是陪你每分每秒似乎让我更快乐，甚至爱你更快乐多，你可以总是把我的脸上露出大大的微笑。
```

Even no trying just accompany you every second seems to make me happier, even love you more, You can always make my face show a big smile.

```
你的吻是真的可爱，你给最好的拥抱。我真的不想过要失去你，它的想法是最可怕的事情。
```

Your kiss was truly cute, you gave the best hug. I really never though of losing you, It's idea was the most frightening.

```
没有言语和行动将永远能够描述你是我的最爱。我过于欢喜欢喜要能够说你属于我。人们说没有人是完美的但对我来说你是完美的婴儿。
```

Nothing will be able to describe you are my favorite. I am over joy to say you belong with me. People say no one is perfect but for me you are the perfect baby.

```
我幸福和幸运的女孩要做你的情人在这整个世界。你特别的吻是最好的。
```

I am a lucky girl with happiness to become your lover in this world, your special kiss was the best.

```
还记得我们曾从小计划我们的关系。肯定你那可爱的故事可能已经忘了。我想再次提醒你。要记住这个故事
```

Still remember we had plan our relationship since young. I am very sure you had forgot that cute story of yours. I want remind you again.

```
我们共享相同的饭盒和矿泉水瓶。
```

We share the same lunch box and water bottle.

```
你玩我的头发。你故意推着我，也爱会迫使你。
```

You play my hair, push me purposely also love to force you.

```
我们庆祝我们的生日在一起，消减我们的蛋糕在一起，一起享受。
```

We celebrate our birthday together, cut our cake and enjoy it together.

```
如果任何一个女孩来给你做你的朋友，我告诉她 你是我的男朋友说请让别人替你的朋友。
```

If any girl came to be your friend, I tell her you are my boyfriend please ask others to be your friend.

```
我完成你的家庭作业。现在作为扩展顺便说一下我们的成长过程。
```

I finished your homework. Now for expand meanwhile talk about our growth process.

```
但我们仍然是好朋友，你却像一个不同的女孩。
```

But we are still friends, you are like a different girl.

```
在这一天，你在骗上给那女孩一把ak步枪。
```

This day, you lie to the girl on an AK rifle.

```
所以你跟我说清，心里很难过。那么这就是我们的出发点。然后我们似乎喜欢彼此
```

And so correct with me, felt very sad. This is our starting point, and we seem to like each other.

```
你可以写我一篇论文
```

You can write me a paper

```
现在我们已经进入大学,你一直和我想要在其他大学第二个大学中
```

Now we had enter University, You've been at other universities, and I want a second university.

```
握住我的手，然后你说你爱我，我也爱你，甚至在我的手上的一个吻。
```

Hold my hand, and you say you love me, I love you too, even kiss on my hand.

```
现在我们常做的事情。那么我们的研究就是它已释放它。
```

Now we often do. So our study is that it has been released it.

```
然后你会回来到勒克瑙返回然后有一天你把我叫到一些东西。然后上午你要嫁给我和医管局会在说话。然后你带我回家迎接他的父母去叶片。收养我你父母那边但你母亲_被剥夺。然后我们去我家问他的妈妈对爸爸找出关于你的所有第一生气 但我说服每个人往往都同意，然后做我们好的婚姻。你做你的妻子再次感到_许多天后，我们发现你的父母在附近集镇。他们看见那离，我们让他们感到伤心哭泣那么你看到的喉咙。然后很高兴我除了，然后我们开始生活乐趣。
```

This is very complicated, I had tried my best to understand but I failed.

```
我今天，爱你胜过我爱过你昨天

每分钟都给你带来靠近一点

新的感情开始在我的心为你

希望我在你的身边不是英里

只是为了把你抱在我怀里，并告诉

你我爱你，我希望我能在附

近的时候你感觉悲伤，或只是

抱着你，如果你是悲伤和忧郁

给你一些安慰和爱过你关心你

与您，看日落，在悬崖上跳海的，在

那里和你在一起直到第二天太阳升起
```

Today, I love you more than yesterday. Every minutes will bring you closer, new feelings in my heart starts for you, Hope you not miles away from me. Just want to hug you in my arms and tell you I love you, I hope I can be your side when you felt sad or just hug you, if you are sad and gloomy, I can comfort you love you care you. watch the sun set with you on the cliff, be with you till next morning when the sun rise.

```
“我爱你这么多我__”
```

"I love you so much"

```
“你的小天使”
```

"Your angel"

```
仙人
```

Comment: And you typed it all out. Man I could give you a medal for this!

Comment: Bro.I appreciate ur efforts from the bottom of my heart.A big thnks to u for deciphering this and typing so much.Thnk u SO MUCH.

Comment: U R A KIND OF PERSON WHICH RESTORES OUR FAITH IN HUMANITY

Comment: +1 Wow! You typed it all out!